# Given that you can set the output of a flip flop the way you want regardless its prior state, why it is considered a sequential device?

Tags: flipflop

The literature states that a SR flip flop is a sequential device and that sequential devices are those whose output depends on its *current inputs* and *prior state*. However, that doesn't make sense to me: flip flops are the basic building blocks of some memories and I wonder how useful a memory can be if its next state depends on its prior state. That would be a very bizarre kind of storage! You *have* to have the ability to write anything you need to and, in fact, that is exactly what a flip flop allows you to do. So, my question is: am I missing something (conceptually speaking) or in fact a flip flop does not comply with the definition of sequential logic? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Virtually all functional devices are initialized to a known state on power up (or stay electrically alive to maintain a known state.  For memory, being able to set or reset a specific bit is what it is all about.  What are you not understanding?

Comment: i actually understood your question.it is an interesting one.  i will take some time when i get home to research and answer. i also recommend adding more relevant tags to the question.

Comment: First, sorry if my question sounded a bit confusing, English is not my first language!! 
The way a sequential device is defined ("unlike combinational devices, sequential devices are those whose current output depends on the current inputs and prior state") doesn't seem to properly describe a flip flop because its output is uniquely defined by its current inputs. So, I ask why on Earth flip flops are considered sequential once they doen't meet the definition.

Comment: *"... its output is uniquely defined by its current inputs."* No! See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of a FF depends on not only the present values of its inputs, but also on the previous values of those inputs. This is the definition of a sequential circuit.

In other words, there are combinations of input values for which the output can be in either of two states — which one is determined by the past history of the input values. Internal feedback gives the circuit "memory".

Comment: Hum, I think I've got what I missed so far: indeed you can write anything you want to the Q output by properly setting the S or R inputs, _regardless_ the prior state. HOWEVER, once you did that, the FF will store the value you wrote even if you unassert the inputs; i.e., it will "remember" what was wrote and that's why it is sequential (and not combinational). Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 5):

What is the current output state of this FlipFlop?

```
   _______
0-|S     Q|-?
0-|R      |
  |_______|
```

It depends on the previous state!

Comment: Christian, that case woundn't be the one in which the output is “undefined” since the output it is inconsistent (both Set and Reset inputs asserted)?

Comment: No, he's showing them as both *negated*.